# htaccess georedirect, excluding referrers

Tags: .htaccess

looking for a rather unconventional htaccess solutions but can't quite figure it out

we're rebuilding our web presence entirely and one issue we're trying to tackle is a simple re-direct htaccess.

the planned flow will be; user visits any site such as:
xx.foo.com where xx is country code. a globally implanted htaccess georedirect sends the user to the correct place.

Our checkout system is on foo.com so the user will be send there regardless but.. they need to be sent to their local subdomain **first** to get the relevant currency & locale data to submit to the checkout.

I can't find a ruleset that allows me to redirect all traffic from foo.com to xx.foo.com **except** any traffic that came from xx.foo.com or xy.foo.com etc.

Comment: Why not just work out the visitor's currency and locale on the `.com` site itself?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it would require a mammoth amount of work on the system we're using to handle billing, it's not a feasible option at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the suggestions!

The solution we chose was indeed to adapt some of the destination locale values by GEO instead